# How to process large amounts of data stored in collections from database queries and print out to richtextbox in specific format?

Tags: c#, database, wpf, observablecollection, data-processing

I am trying to filter through large amounts of data that I put into a collection after returning results from a database query. The query parameters are based on the user's UI filter selections. The problem is that I need to notify the user with a simple "please wait" gui when the user selects a button to generate a message, while in at the same time filtering through that large collection of database results that can have 1000's or more items.

I have tried using a simple thread that I got to work to filter through my collections while the UI is showing that "please wait" window to the user. The issue is that it still takes a long time in certain situations, namely the collection is massive.

I need to output the data to a richtextbox on the main window. In a specific format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what you do, it will always take time to process large amount of data. I suggest you review your use case and go with a different approach depending on your user's needs.

A typical solution is to use paging or progressively displaying the data as it is being loaded, when the goal is to display the data to the user. If the user must work with or edit the entire collection, then there might be a way to divide the collection into workable chunks for the user.

Comment: I am kinda new to large data processing situations. Could you give a brief explanation of paging. Thanks.

Comment: I think what Robert Baron means is that you shouldn't search or output all the data at once. Try to break it into bits (pages) and then provide them to the user based on which page he/she is at (just like a google search does....). Check out Sieve (https://github.com/Biarity/Sieve), it could help with pagination during your database query.